# Event-driven report delivery

Tags: powerbi

I see in Power BI that the user can choose to subscribe to a report.  In that process, they choose the schedule the report will be run and delivered on.

How can a user subscribe to a report to be delivered when an event occurs in the data or an event occurs in an external application.

Here's are examples (using IBM Cognos Analytics):

We have a financial system that has a monthly closing process that occurs on the 8th business day of the month.  Because of weekends and holidays, this date can vary from the 10th to the 13th of the month.  To complicate things even more, we have another system that performs it's monthly close 2 days after the first system, unless it's a Thursday or a Friday, in which case it occurs the following Monday, unless that's a holiday, then it happens on Tuesday.  But rather than schedule monthly financial reports for the 18th of the month to handle all cases, users want the reports as soon as the data is available.  So we implemented a "trigger" in our ETL system (a call to the Cognos SDK) to tell the reporting system that a certain set of reports should be run.

We have a system that is reliable about 70% of the time.  The other 30% of the time, some IT intervention is required to keep things running.  Most of the time, this system provides data to our data mart by 8:00 a.m..  When it requires intervention, the data load is completed late.  We have a process (Cognos Event Studio Agent) that starts running at 9:00 a.m. and runs every hour for 6 hours.  Each time, inspects the data (runs a simple query) to determine if the data has been successfully loaded.  If so, reports are distributed, if not, it will try again later.  Users don't want the data at 9:00 a.m. if it's no good, but they also don't want to wait until the end of the day just to be sure.

How can I do event-driven reporting in Power BI?  Would I use something else in the "Power" platform?  Can this be done using PowerShell?

Comment: Check out Power BI Alerts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-set-data-alerts

Comment: That's extremely limited, totally manual, only allows numeric input, and doesn't solve either problem.  How would I know if the value changed since the last time the query ran?  Are you expecting the user to modify the alert after each time it fires?

Comment: Just pointing out the feature.  To get an alert when a value changes, write a measure that crosses a threshold when today's value is different than yesterday's.   See eg: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Alert-when-data-changes/m-p/1189718#M100933

Comment: Still doesn't solve the problem.  Even if such a thing was possible to craft, given all possible variables, without involving my ETL developer and data modeler, it would still just notify the user that now they need to manually run all of the reports that they need on that schedule.  Since you work at MS and are responding to Power BI questions on SO, I'll assume you are the best authority I can find on this topic -- and that the answer is that it can't be done.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I made a comment instead of an answer intentionally to _not_ say whether it can't be done.  And Microsoft is a big company, and I'm not some sort of ultimate authority on Microsoft stuff.  There are other options involving Paginated Report, Power Automate and PowerShell.  But Power BI Alerts is a simple out-of-the box so I just wanted to make sure you evaluated it.

Comment: It does seem possible to do event driven report delivery using the Power Platform tooling. It looks like alerts can be used to trigger Power Automate flows, which would then allow you to deliver reports or other Power BI content. Ex: https://www.datapears.com/post/data-driven-subscriptions-in-power-bi. What this lacks is the subscription being a driver and the selected delivery options in the subscription being respected. You could design a process following this model (IMO outside of the Power Platform) that uses subscription data as a driver, but that would be an essay and half to describe.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that process (from the link) helps.  It covers only my second example and requires a Power BI dashboard tile to be filtered to a hard-coded value, not compared to the value the last time the data changed.  I suppose I could produce a calculation that returns a number and base the calculation on comparing the current value with the value that was stored, externally, somewhere, the last time the event ran.  
Maybe Power Automate can handle the first example, though.  I assume I can I use something external (PowerShell, C#, etc.) to tell Power Automate to run something.

Comment: I imagine you could get creative and find ways to get the alerts to work for your use case. For example, value of 1 could just be your trigger, and you have a PBI dataset with column values that suit your scenarios in which you flip the value between 1 and 0 (which could be done ad-hoc with XMLA endpoint) when you want to trigger the report delivery. That's getting pretty creative tho. You would likely be better off just using PBI API to retrieve, deliver, or embed content directly based off of events yourself using your automation tool of choice.